# Swift: Asynchronous Loop with Recursion for GeoCoding

Tags: swift, recursion, geocode

Only one GeoCode request can be happening at a time, and they are async, so I need to start the next one as soon as the previous one finishes. I have it working like this:

```
func one() {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        let one = myPlacesFakeData[0]

        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(one.address, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Unable to Reverse Geocode Location (\(error))")
            } else {
                if let placemarks = placemarks, let placemark = placemarks.first {
                    myPlacesFakeData[0].latitude = placemark.location?.coordinate.latitude
                    myPlacesFakeData[0].longitude = placemark.location?.coordinate.longitude
                } else {
                    print("No Matching Address Found")
                }
            }

            self.two()
        })
    }

    func two() {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        let two = myPlacesFakeData[1]

        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(two.address, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Unable to Reverse Geocode Location (\(error))")
            } else {
                if let placemarks = placemarks, let placemark = placemarks.first {
                    myPlacesFakeData[1].latitude = placemark.location?.coordinate.latitude
                    myPlacesFakeData[1].longitude = placemark.location?.coordinate.longitude
                } else {
                    print("No Matching Address Found")
                }
            }
            self.three()
        })
    }

    func three() {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        let three = myPlacesFakeData[2]

        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(three.address, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Unable to Reverse Geocode Location (\(error))")
            } else {
                if let placemarks = placemarks, let placemark = placemarks.first {
                    myPlacesFakeData[2].latitude = placemark.location?.coordinate.latitude
                    myPlacesFakeData[2].longitude = placemark.location?.coordinate.longitude
                } else {
                    print("No Matching Address Found")
                }
            }

        })
    }
```

But this is ghetto and depends on there being exactly three places I'm trying to GeoCode.

I think I need a recursive function and a counter, but I'm not sure how to write this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a playground that shows one approach. You can use a function that will call itself and accumulate results that eventually calls a completion handler once all addresses have been geocoded. You could do a lot better with error handling and wrapping in better types but it's a good starting point!

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa
import CoreLocation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

func geoCode(addresses: [String], results: [CLPlacemark] = [], completion: @escaping ([CLPlacemark]) -> Void ) {
    guard let address = addresses.first else {
        completion(results)
        return
    }

    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in

        var updatedResults = results

        if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
            updatedResults.append(placemark)
        }

        let remainingAddresses = Array(addresses[1..<addresses.count])

        geoCode(addresses: remainingAddresses, results: updatedResults, completion: completion)
    }
}

let addresses = ["1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500", "1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA"]

geoCode(addresses: addresses) { results in
    print("Got back \(results.count) results")
}
```